# Is it Safe to open port 35000:40000 for FTP data connections

Tags: iptables, vsftpd

I recently got hacked so im being careful when changing the settings in my CentOS 7 iptables. I just opened ports 35000 to 40000 for FTP PASV connection, will this represent any security risks?

Comment: Please select a favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a normal ftp connection, you got a security risk by default, due to the connection is not being encrypted. You will risk presenting critical data to an outside party. If you run a ssh server on that system you can use sftp insted to tunnel your ftp session over the ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

You may reduce the likely hood of a random attack but your data is still visible in transit. There are 2 better options:

1) Install a SSL certificate in your FTP server to secure the data. [Digital Ocean: Configure vsftpd to Use SSL/TLS on Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjADahUKEwi7q8qe0f7IAhVIWD4KHcV3BWE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps&usg=AFQjCNE1m7r6mk7U_NQPq_ySvLt7cs0IgA&sig2=zULpQZT2Z-CxKm6smJmJGA). This assumes your using VSFTPD. But there are plenty of how to's for other servers as well.

2) **BEST OPTION** Connect using SFTP. You likely already have a SSH connection if your changing server ports so dump the FTP server and use the SSH built in FTP function. Most FTP clients can connect to SFTP. (Not FTPS) I know winSCP and filezilla can. For bonus points generate a certificate and have password-less login (Its counter-intuitive but its more secure) [Generate Key Pair for SSH and SFTP](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/)